# How can I slow down the time between animations?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to slow down the time between animations in my cycle.

I've tried increasing the animation time for my keyframes, but that didn't work.

```
    span {
     animation: rotateWordsFirst 15s linear infinite 0s;

      &:nth-child(2) { 
        animation-delay: 5s; 
        }

        &:nth-child(3) { 
        animation-delay: 10s; 
             }

        &:nth-child(4) { 
        animation-delay: 15s; 
        }
    }

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
     0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I was hoping to keep the text visible for a longer period of time between animations, but everything I've tried seems to throw off my animation cycle.

I've been using this tutorial:
http://www.css3transition.com/rotating-words-css-animations/

Comment: Add a SCSS tag or whatever post-processing you are using and it would help if you posted the compiled CSS for those of us who just know CSS.

Comment: Can you  add the `rotateWordsFirst ` animation to  your css?

Comment: Show us your keyframes

Comment: @ChrisW. just added them

Comment: Just provide more time before you `translateY` back out by tweaking your keyframes; Eg; change like 17% and 20% to like 75% and 77% respectively then your animation-delay's will act as I think you're expecting (provided I'm understanding your intent correctly anyway), cheers!

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried that, but it just makes the text in the animation loop overlap (so two of them show at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem when making a semi complex city animation with cars, planes and trains moving all at the same time.

I then came across this article from Chris Coyier:

https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/

> here is an animation-delay property, but that won't help us here. That delays the start of the animation, but after it's started it runs continuously.

So, what he suggests, similar to what ChrisW was trying to explain, is to include the delays into your keyframe logic:

EXAMPLE

My original animation lasts 4 seconds, I want it to run infinitely but with a delay of 1s at end. This means I have to add the delay to the total animation time, in this case, 4s + 1s = 5s. Apply the following changes:

```
.your-element {
  animation: name-of-your-animation 5s infinite;
}
```

Now, for the keyframes, let us assume we had something like this:

```
@keyframes name-of-your-animation {
  0% {
    //do something
  }
  25% {
    // do something
  }
  50% {
    //do something
  }
  75% {
    //do something
  }
  100% {
   // do something
  }
}
```

We need to factor in the 1s delay at the end, so our animation must take place in 4s out of 5s, in other words, 4/5th's of the animation or 80% of the 100%:

```
@keyframes name-of-your-animation {
  0% {
    //do something
  }
  50% {
    // do something
    opacity:0.5;
  }
  /* Finish changes by here, as an example, let's think of moving opacity from 0 to 1, gradually or not */
  79% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  /* Between 80% and 100%, nothing changes, so the 'end state' is repeated */
  80%, 100% {
   // do something
   opacity:1;
  }
}
```

Give it a try and let us know if you need additional help.
Cheers
G